# How to Speed Up Function to Save 1 Sheet as PDF to Google Drive Folder in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

The below code works wonderfully to save only the 'PO Template' sheet of my Google Sheet file in PDF format to the designated Google Drive folder, 'Purchase_Orders'.  The only issue is the function takes 10+ seconds to run.  Is there something within the code that can be condensed to speed up the script run process for this one?

```
function checkSheet() {
  var sheetName = "POTemplate";
  var folderID = "Purchase_Orders";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var poNo = sourceSheet.getRange("G5").getValue();
  var shipTo = sourceSheet.getRange("E9").getValue();
  var pdfName = shipTo + " Purchase Order " + poNo;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderID);
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(folder));
   var source = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
   source.copyTo(source, {contentsOnly: true});
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
   for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
     destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i])}}; 
  var theBlob = 
destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.next().createFile(theBlob);
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  var strUrl = newFile.getUrl()
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("NewTab");
  html.strUrl = strUrl
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html.evaluate(), 
"Congratulations!  "+ pdfName + " is now saved.")
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're cloning your current spreadsheet, deleting every sheet but one, then converting it to pdf, and then deleting the cloned spreadsheet. Why not just hide every sheet in your current spreadsheet that you don't want printed, then convert it to PDF, and then unhide the sheets again?

Comment: Looking to eliminate as many manual steps/mouse clicks as possible.  Following your advice via Apps Script might be the answer, but having our staff complete those steps manually may prove slower than the existing code.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can hide sheets with Apps Script: `wb.getSheets().forEach(function (s) { if (s.getName() != "POTemplate" ) { s.hideSheet(); } ); /* make pdf from wb */ wb.getSheets().forEach(function (s) { s.unhideSheet(); });`

Comment: I have found that `getRange` and `setRange` take a lot of time, try to have as little as possible, and keep the data in array instead of finding it in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

There is my Execution transcript of your code.

[image]

It seems `File.makeCopy` takes 50% of time. Also `Folder.createFile` wants 15%.

This means that your optimization will be minimal in the future.

Comment: How does this vary with size of the workbook, and with sheet count? Also, you should contrast the current approach with an alternative like I mention in my comment on the question before stating that the execution cannot be optimized.